# How to sign in multiple account using GoogleSignIn ios

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm trying to create an app to integrate calendar of multiple users together. This would require the user to sign in to multiple google accounts.

I use `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn() to` do sign in.

After the user is signed in to an account and press sign in button again, 
`GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()` is called and

immediately the delegate

`sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!)`

is called with the same user.

No sign in page is shown,

`sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!)` isn't called.

I'm unable to sign in/switch to other google account without logging out to the signed in account.

Comment: I dont think you can sign in with multiple gmail accounts at a same time. First you have to logout the first user then login other user./